# Obtain the result of stored procedure in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Can I get multiple select from distinct tables (many rows) in just one store procedure in mysql and retrieve those result in nodejs?

Like in .NET with SQL Server we can use use "sqlnextresult"

[IMAGE FROM STORE PROCEDURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEFe2.png)
[image]

Comment: I'm using  "mysql": "^2.13.0" with Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example using `mssql` node package, you can find [here](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) the documentation about this package.

```
var sql = require('mssql'),
    connectionObj = {
        user: 'myUser',
        password: 'myPassword',
        server: 'http://mysqlserver.whatever'
        options: {
            database: 'myDB'
        }
    };

/**
 * Opens connection to sql server.
 *
 * @return {Object} Connection object.
 */
function openConnection() {
    var connection = new sql.Connection(connectionObj);
    return connection;
};

/**
 * Closes connection.
 *
 * @param {Object} connection - Connection Object.
 * @return {Promise} Promise.
 */
function closeConnection(connection) {
    return connection.close();
};

/**
 * Does a request to sql server.
 *
 * @param {Object} connection - Connection object.
 * @param {string} query - Query string to compute.
 * @return {Promise} Promise.
 */
function doRequest(connection, query) {
    return connection.request().query(query);
};

/**
 * Gets Request.
 *
 * @param {Object} connection - Connection object.
 */
function getRequest(connection) {
    return new sql.Request(connection);
};

var request, conn = openConnection();

// First open the connection with DB (method uses the object created at the begining.
conn.connect()
    .then(function() {
        // Now creates a Request.
        request = getRequest(conn);
        // Executes your stored procedure.
        return request.execute('usp_get_Masters');
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result); // Here in result you have the result of the stored procedure execution.
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: What i want to do is: `getMainRoutes(cb) {
        conn.query('usp_get_Masters()', cb);
    }`         , Can that execution retrieve the 3 results of the store procedure i've sent? , I mean like the callback return => results[0] for 1 table , results[1] for other table and results[2] for the third table ??

Comment: The structure of result depends on how you have made the stored procedure, in your case, i think as you said, you will have in 'result' 3 occurs in the array, each occurs as each select you post. Have you tried my code?